# GeoPandas plot choropleth line color

Tags: geopandas, matplotlib

I'm using GeoPandas to create a categorical choropleth of my data. I managed to get the correct colormap applied to the polygon fill but there are tiny slivers between the polygons that I would like to remove. What is the appropriate way to do this? I thought about the following options:

1. Apply the same color (same as used for fill) to each polygon line
2. Make the lines transparent
3. Set the line width to 0

This is my code so far:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.set_xlim(xmin, xmax)
ax.set_ylim(ymin , ymax)
gdf.plot(ax=ax,column=column,cmap=cmap,categorical=True,linewidth=0)
plt.axis('off')
fig.savefig(output_filename+".pdf",dpi=300)
fig.savefig(output_filename+".jpg",dpi=300)
```

Gdf is a geodataframe with multiPolygons. The result looks like this. As you can see, there are weird slivers between the polygons. The shapefile does not contain any gaps.

[image]

Comment: Do you mean white lines within the colored areas?

Comment: Yes, adjacent polygons sometimes have the same color. Ideally I would only view the polygon fill, no outlines whatsoever.

Comment: I found a way around the issue by splitting up the the data and plotting each category as a separate layer.

Comment: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1JAVDxIKPN8IUYXwFUUBjYtf_7wF0op0d